# Page of user profiles

Tags: contacts, userprofiles

I'd like to add a Contacts app on a SharePoint Online site which displays all user profiles (the profiles as seen within the SharePoint admin center).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting all users from the Office 365 SharePoint admin center directly isn't possible, you can get users one by one, or specify an array of users to get, but to get ALL users in one request from user profile service isn't possible.

What I would do, is to query the the user information list inside the site collection itself to get a list of users added to that site collection no matter of their permission level. This list can be found in every site collection at: 
https://Office365.sharepoint.com/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx

So your add-in can query this list as any other SharePoint list, and you'll get user info required, and links to their profiles, the downside of it is, it won't get users who aren't added to the current site collection.